# Unable to get React JS hello world working

Tags: reactjs, jsx, babeljs

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>React JS</title>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="ex"></div>
 <script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello</h1>,document.getElementById('ex'));
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to get this intro example working. 
Whenever I run this code I get a '<' on my browser.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the order in which scripts are loaded and you were loading `babel-core` **asynchronously**.. also you were seeing `<` because of your syntax error `<<!DOCTYPE html>`, it should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>React JS</title>
 <script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="ex"></div>
 <script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello</h1>,document.getElementById('ex'));
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think that an answer is needed because of one < character a comment is enough :)

Comment: @IlanHasanov But that's not the only issue, he's loading `babel-core` asynchronously so sometimes his script might work (if babel-core is loaded) sometimes not..

Comment: Sorry haven't seen it

Comment: Thanks guys :). I just started out with React and I had a very hard time figuring it out.

Comment: If that's the case, Then i recommend you learn Javascript first, It will definitely help you understand how React or any framework/modules based on Javascript work.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem: showing only `<`

#### Reason:

Typo on `<<!DOCTYPE html>`

### Solution:

remove `<`

---

### Problem: not showing rendered content

#### Reason:

`async` attribute on `script`
when `async` is present, script executed asynchronously with the rest of the page. Mean browser already rendered your page before `babel` get a chance to convert `jsx`

### Solution:

remove `async` from `script` and `defer` is also unnecessary